# Is it possible to remove 'Standard Colors' section in PowerPoint 2010 color palette?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, templates, color-theme

By creating template in PowerPoint 2010, is it possible to remove 'Standard Colors' section from the color palette drop-down menu so that only custom theme colors would be available to use?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe it's possible to remove either the Standard or Recent colors sections, though you can modify the Recent colors section that users start with by modifying the XML in your template.

A section of this page explains how to modify recent colors:
http://www.brandwares.com/bestpractices/category/powerpoint/page/2/

But as soon as users start choosing their own colors, any default recent colors you've provided will be overwritten.